# Spring Boot and maxActive setting

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ibm-cloud

We are deploying Spring Boot microservices into Cloud Foundry in IBM Bluemix. The microservices all talk to a PostGres database, and it appears by default that each service is creating 10 connections that they hold open that I assume is for connection pooling.  The problem we run into is that with our Postgres instance we are limited to 100 connections, so we are at times exceeding that limit.

We did some research and found that this setting may help:

**spring.datasource.maxActive=5**

We put that setting in our yml file for the microservices, and that helped with some of our deployments. It seems like Spring Boot sometimes adheres to the settings of maxActive and sometimes not.

I say that because when I look at the active connections in Postgres I see some of the services adhering to that limit and others that don't.  We checked all the yml files, and they are all set the same.  A few of us reviewed this closely to make sure that all of the yml files were the same.

Is maxActive the right setting to use to limit the connections to Postgres?
Are there other settings we should be using?

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Brian

Comment: It depends on which Spring Boot version you are using (and that is information you haven't included in your post).

Comment: Thanks for replying. We are using 1.4.0.RELEASE.

Comment: Then it depends on which datasource you use which property to set. For tomcat-jdbc it is `spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active` if you use another one check the documentation.